# Dump a Disk MBR into a bootable USB.. Is It Possible?

Tags: boot, grub, mbr

**Reason:**
I have multiple system images on my hard disk unified with grub2 bootloader. I want to reinstall Windows 10 that exists on a particular partition.

**Issue:**
The bootloader will be replaced when done installing Windows 10, and can't restore my grub boot menu without installing 3rd party software on Windows 10.

**Imaginary Scenario:**
Backup my current grub bootloader menu into a bootable USB. and when booting from this USB I could boot into my linux image and fix the grub-bootloader there.

Is there any software that could do that
Thanks in advance. Any solutions or alternatives are appreciated.

Comment: Is the computer using EFI?

Comment: No, My BIOS supports legacy only and my hard disk is set to MBR as well

Comment: Why qould you need to install software on Windows? Linux is enough. See [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) and [more](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu). But better take a backup image of the disk before starting.

Comment: Thank you!! This one [Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/) solves every bit of the problem. However. It detects all system images on the disk as my purpose was. But was wondering if someone could get a copy of the master boot record of an HDD.

Comment: Burning to USB (not for portable purposes I mean) and booting in the same PC. It has the same uid of the disk and such..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting problems after the installation of Windows destroyed the Grub bootloader,
can be corrected.

A good tool to use is the free
[Super Grub2 Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/).